# How to solve "Call to undefined function dbase_open() " error in windows

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, gmp, dbf

Hi i want to load DBF file to mysql, am using xampp,php version 5.5.6

i had write the below code,

But am getting Error ---

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function dbase_open() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\imports\import_geo.php on line 47

```
$dbf = dbase_open('OUTLETS/regions.dbf', 0);
$num_records = dbase_numrecords($dbf);
for($i=1;$i<=$num_records;$i++)
{
    $record = dbase_get_record_with_names($dbf, $i);
    $stmt_bricks->execute(array(
        ':id' => $next_brick_id,
        ':type' => 'Region',
        ':code' => $record['REG_CODE'],
        ':descr' => $record['REG_DESC'],
    ));
    $regions_code_to_id[$record['REG_CODE']] = $next_brick_id++;
}
```

I saw in one article, we have to uncomment `extension=php_gmp.dll`  in php.ini, but in my php.ini 
`extension=php_gmp.dll` is not available, please help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have to _install_ the extension, then enable it. Typical distributions pack that extension with php, seems not to be the case with the one you use... You can check if it is available inside the output of a testwise `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` you run.

Comment: `dbase_open` is part of the dBase extension. What makes you think that you need to enable GMP for this?

Answer (score 5):

dBase is moved to PECL for now

```
yum install php-pear
pecl install dbase
```

After successful execution, you'll need to add "extension=dbase.so" to your php.ini

Or create **dbase.ini** in /etc/php.d with

```
extension=dbase.so
```

[fliber.net](http://www.fliber.net) uses this

Comment: This helped me so much, thank you. I couldn't get dbase libs in PHP 5.5

Answer (score 4):

How to on Ubuntu (15.04):

1) install php5-dev

```
sudo apt-get install php5-dev
```

2) install dbase via pecl

```
sudo pecl install dbase
```

3) load extension

3.1) create `dbase.ini` file in `/etc/php5/mods-available/` directory with this content:

```
extension=dbase.so
```

3.2) create sym link in `/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/` directory:

```
sudo ln -s ../../mods-available/dbase.ini 20-dbase.ini
```

4) restart apache

Answer (score 0):

Check is there dbase extension(php_dbase.dll) is there in 'C:\xampp\php\ext'.
if dll file there then check is it enabled or not in php.ini file. if not enabled follow from step 3.

if it's not there then follow below steps.

1. download (refer below link) php_dbase.dll file according to your system and php version.

   Link - https://pecl.php.net/package/dbase
2. add downloaded 'php_dbase.dll' file to in 'C:\xampp\php\ext'
3. open php.ini file
4. search 'extension=', you will find many extension there.
5. add below line after all extension list.
   'extension=php_dbase.dll' (without quote)(no issue if add this line at the end of file.

Restart apache server.
it will start working in local - windows system.

Note:- update file name with 'php_dbase.dll' if file name is different.

Comment: What's the reason to link to a repository that hasn't seen any updates since two years, and which also links to another page in bold letters?

Comment: i tried multiple solution for 3 days, not a single worked, then i found this solution, that's why added this answer.

there is no other repository, for php dbase, where i found dbase extension.

Comment: Why not use the official builds from https://pecl.php.net/package/dbase?

Comment: thanks for sharing link, i checked, it contain latest dll file.
we should using https://pecl.php.net/package/dbase and dowlnload dll file according to php version.

Answer (score -1):

You need to check in PHP directory is file php_gmp.dll enable and if it does, then in php.ini add this string  "extension=php_gmp.dll" in extensions section.

If file does not exist then add it to php in apache - http://www.dll4free.com/php_gmp.dll.html

May be Open server will be better them XAMPP - http://translate.google.ru/translate?sl=ru&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=ru&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fopen-server.ru%2Fdownload.html&act=url
It have many PHP versions, mySQL, PostgresQL, MongoDB, memcache, administration tools, regular updates, english support in forum and free!

Comment: i did the above step, but Am getting error “the procedure entry point php_checkuil could not be located in the dynamic link libarary php5ts.dll”

&  PHP startup: unable to load dynamic libarary 'C\xampp\ext\php_dbase.dll, The specified procedure could not be founded.

Comment: Why should enabling the GMP extension help when `dbase_open`  is not found?

Answer (score -2):

check in your `xampp/php/ext` folder for `php_gmp.dll` ,if the extension is there add this `extension=php_gmp.dll` to php.ini file in `xampp/php/php.ini`. else add this dll to `xampp/php/ext` and do the above step  restart your apache server

Comment: Why should enabling the GMP extension help when `dbase_open`  is not found?