# Installing dBase extension in XAMPP

Tags: php, php-extension, dbase

I have a problem with installing dBase extension in XAMPP with PHP 5.5.11.
I added `php_dbase.dll` to php/ext folder and added following line to the `php.ini` file:

```
extension=php_dbase.dll
```

But when I try this code in my script:

```
dbase_open('file.dbf');
```

I got an error message:

> Call to undefined function dbase_open()'

How to properly install `dBase` extension?

Comment: In WHM, go to `Software > Module Installers` then click in `Manage` in PHP PECL line. `Search for "dbase" > Install`!

CENTOS 6.8 x86_64 kvm – cPanel & WHM 64.0 (build 36)

Answer (score 3):

Try with this link:
http://pecl.php.net/package/dbase/5.1.0/windows

In my case i have:
XAMPP 1.8.3 
[PHP: 5.5.15]

And i use: 
php_dbase-5.1.0-5.5-ts-vc11-x86.zip

Download the correct version for your PHP windows environmet.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You need to check in PHP directory is file `php_gmp.dll` enable and if it does, then in `php.ini` add this string in extensions section:

```
extension=php_gmp.dll
```

For more info go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22344867/how-to-solve-call-to-undefined-function-dbase-open-error-in-windows).

Comment: Thanks, I did it already, but it didn't help. I restarted the Apache server too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to to check the php_dbase.dll is compatiable with your php version.

here i am using php 5.3.27 ThreadSafe version with vc9 and i downloaded the php_dbase-5.3-svn-20101022-vc9-x86.zip file from http://downloads.php.net/pierre/ and i did same all above you mentioned.

everything is working for me.