# Call to undefined function dbase_open() error

Tags: php, html, dbf, dbase

I'm trying to work my dbf file to get to open using dbase_open and I'm encountering an error  (Call to undefined function dbase_open() error)

I've already uncommented the extension=php_gmp.dll in php.ini. I've tried to downloading the package http://pecl.php.net/package/dbase/5.1.0/windows according to this forum  [Installing dBase extension in XAMPP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24953910/installing-dbase-extension-in-xampp)
and I'm still having no luck with working on it....

Php version: 5.3 
Text Editor: Netbeans

Please help me with this? :(

```
include 'config.php';
 $tbl = "CC";

// Path to dbase file
    $db_path = "C:\xampp\htdocs\DbftoSQL\something.DBF";

    // Open dbase file
    $dbh = dbase_open($db_path, 0)
    or die("Error! Could not open dbase database file '$db_path'.");
```

Comment: What directory is the `php_gmp.dll` file located in?

Comment: C:\xampp\php\ext 
I have the .dll in the folder

Answer (score 1):

You can check this answers and try out.
    **[How to solve "Call to undefined function dbase_open() " error in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22344867/how-to-solve-call-to-undefined-function-dbase-open-error-in-windows)**

And Try to restart Apache service if any changes for php.ini file.It will work.

Comment: I tried the steps which are only for windows there and I'm still not having any luck :(

Answer (score 0):

download (refer below link) php_dbase.dll file according to your system.

Link - https://github.com/nufue/pecl-dbase-windows

add downloaded 'php_dbase.dll' file to in 'C:\xampp\php\ext'

open php.ini file

search 'extension=', you will find many extension there.
add below line after all extension list.
'extension=php_dbase.dll' (without quote)(no issue if add this line at the end of file.

Restart apache server.
it will start working in local - windows system.

Note:- update file name with 'php_dbase.dll' if file name is different.